# Are bipartite Moore graphs Hamiltonian?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-geometry, hamiltonian-graphs

This is motivated by a [computer-generated conjecture](https://github.com/math1um/objects-invariants-properties/issues/437) that bipartite distance-regular graphs are hamiltonian. I decided to check the case of Moore graphs first.

The cycles and complete bipartite graphs are hamiltonian (trivial).

The girth-6 graphs are the incidence graphs of the projective planes. The classical finite-field planes are hamiltonian by
[Singer](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1938-043-03/S0002-9947-1938-1501951-4/S0002-9947-1938-1501951-4.pdf), but there are lots of nonclassical planes.

And what about the girth-8 and girth-12 case?

**EDIT:** Corrected the girth-6 case as pointed out by Gordon Royle.

Comment: Singer’s result is about the classical Desarguesian projective plane defined over a finite field. There are huge numbers of non-classical planes, and at first sight I cannot see why they should be Hamiltonian.

Comment: The collinearity graph, i.e. the distance 2 graph on one part of the bipartition, in the girth 8/12 case is Hamiltonian (at least when the number of vertices is large enough) by the results of Krivelevich and Sudakov (https://people.math.ethz.ch/~sudakovb/pseudo-hamiltonian.pdf). But I am not sure if this implies Hamiltonicity of the the bipartite graph. May be I am missing something obvious ...

Answer (score 2):

This recent paper of Sato and Suzuki shows that the graphs corresponding to some classical generalized quadrangles are indeed Hamiltonian:

Sato, H. & Suzuki, H. Graphs and Combinatorics (2018). https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-018-1940-6